# How to cut text by given condition (with special characters) in a script

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cut

I have a file which looks like this (myfile.txt):

```
{"total":25,"p":1,"ps":100,"paging":{"pageIndex":1,"pageSize":100,"total":25},"issues":[{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of},
{the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's},
{standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a},
{type specimen book.}
```

I want to cut these text:

```
{"total":25,"p":1,"ps":100,"paging":{"pageIndex":1,"pageSize":100,"total":25},"issues":[
```

I may use 2 methods here (any method is possible).

1. I have to remove the line start with `{"total"` and end with  `"issues":[` (( including `{"total"` and `"issues":["` ))
2. I have to remove the all text before `"issues":[` text ((including `"issues":[` ))

then output would be

```
{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of},
{the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's},
{standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a}
{type specimen book.}
```

I tried this

```
cat myfile.txt | sed 's/{"total"//g' | sed 's/"issues":[//g'
```

but it occurs errors.

Can someone help me to figure out this?

Comment: I'm curious -- where does your input data come from? (A lot of it _looks like_ JSON, but then some clearly isn't spec-compliant).

Comment: Please show content of `myfile.txt`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Could you refer "myfile.txt" which is indicated.  it is just a text file. just ignore the pattern.

Comment: @Cyrus  I have put it in top. that is the content. could your refer it pls

Comment: In your example, you could cut everything from the start of the text up to (including) the first `[`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^{"total[^[]*\[//' input_file
{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of},
{the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's},
{standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a},
{type specimen book.}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator `s///` of sed for this:

```
sed -i 's/{"total.*issues":\[\(.*\)/\1/' t.txt
```

- `{"total`: pattern starts with that
- `.*`: anything between the beginning and end of pattern
- `issues":\[`: the end of the pattern
- `\(.*\)`: everything else in the rest of the line
- `\1`: replaced by the content between parenthesis